# enabling twitter player cards in branch.io

Tags: branch.io

so my branch.io regular twitter cards are working just fine (with cover pic and all), but my app is a music streaming app
so my question is, how can i enable twitter player cards with branch.io links?

with regards
Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following Twitter tags to your Branch links

1. `$twitter_player` : The link your audio file or music file
2. `$twitter_player_width, $twitter_player_height`: Set the player's width & height in pixels.
3. `$twitter_card: player`: Specify the twitter card type as Player.

Note: If you set the **$twitter_card** parameter to Player you need to whitelist you link subdomain on the Twitter Card Validator [here](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator). Just paste the Branch link you created with '$twitter_card: player' parameter in the validator and you will be provided with a link to whitelist your subdomain.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the audio url as in the stream URL right? (its an api call after all)

Comment: @armuta i just got whitelisted but facing a weird issue, before enabling the player i had my cards showing fine in mobile, after i added the player string its not showing as a card in the mobile view, just when expanded https://ibb.co/mcLrw5
https://ibb.co/hY08b5

Comment: @a7medo778 have tried pasting your link in the card validator and checking what the error says?

Comment: yep, i am getting its valid https://ibb.co/hzRAPQ , and there is one more strange thing, when in detailed view i can see the play icon appearing, but it should spawn a card instead its just opening it as a link with the player https://ibb.co/ciGGyk
https://ibb.co/d7gujQ while it should look like this https://ibb.co/egLbyk

Comment: note that on web version of twitter it working fine https://ibb.co/gvDzjQ (but no image witht the player), so maybe it has something to do with the passing of the image ?

Comment: @armuta sorry i forgot to mention you above

Comment: I had faced a similar issue when I added a youtube link to the my link. It was just not a valid stream URL. After I replaced the $twitter_player link with the embed URL it worked just fine. Make sure that the URL is a valid steam URL.

Comment: @ Amruta  nope... i reverted back to the regular card

Comment: i tryed everything, its valid, works fine on the website, doesnt work at all in the app (and in both cases could get the "player card" that soundcloud has)

Comment: Could you write into `integrations@branch.io` so that the team could work with your issue?